# How can I use jquery function-1 variable value, inside function-2?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 jQuery events occurring inside a `form`. There is one `select` element inside a `form`:

Event 1 is on select change. It's storing the selected option value in a variable:

```
$('#sm_name').change(function(){
    var option_value = $('#sm_name option:selected').val();
    console.log(option_value);
});
```

Event 2 is on form submit using `$.ajax()`:

```
$("#fb_form").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#message").empty();
    $("#loading").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "POST",                 // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this),     // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,           // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,                 // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData: false,           // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function (data) {    // A function to be called if request succeeds
        }
    });
});
```

How can I change the AJAX URL dynamically for each selected value from the `select` dropdown? Something like this:

```
url: "submit.php?id=" + option_value,
```

Comment: url: "submit.php?id=" + $('#sm_name').val()

Comment: declare var option_value; globally. or use url: "submit.php?id=" +$('#sm_name option:selected').val()

Comment: @DeepakSharma while it would work, global variables should be avoided

Comment: then use url: "submit.php?id=" +$('#sm_name option:selected').val(),

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the value of the `select` within the `submit` handler:

```
$("#fb_form").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#message").empty();
    $("#loading").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php?id=" + $('#sm_name').val(),
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // do something on request success...
        }
    });
});
```

Note the use of `val()` directly on the `select` element - you don't need to access the selected option to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get value from `dropdown` to `submit form` to the url which is selected in `dropdown`

```
url: "submit.php?id="+$('#sm_name').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to jQuery, in JavaScript you can use a feature called closures to use variables from outer scope:

```
var outerScopeVariable = null;

function a() {
    outerScopeVariable = 'hello world';
}

function b() {
    console.log(outerScopeVariable); // will output 'hello world' if
                                     // function a() has previously been called.
}
```